# Excel Compare two columns for matches or differences in the same row based on the header

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

There are 45 columns on `Sheet1`
Every time the column are not coming in the same place, in the `Sheet1` there are two important columns that is **Work Country** and **Base Country**, where I am checking if values from both columns are same or different: if they are same, the output in column **Status** should be *Local*, *Expat* otherwise.
But when I tryed calculating my formula the result was **#Name?**
Can you help me with this issue? I have attached the screen shot of my worksheet.
My Excel file includes VBA Modules as well, so I am ok with either formula or VBA code.

This is the formula I have used:

```
=IF(Work Geography,A2)=IFS(Work Country,B2)
```

[image]

Comment: Is your second column *Base Country* or *Work Geography* ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i am matching the Column A & Column B

Comment: What is the purpose of `=IF(Work Geography,A2)`? It will throw error, unless you don't have boolean values. Are `Work Geography` and `Work Country` named ranges? It will throw error otherwise as well.

Comment: #NAME error will come when a function is not defined or misspelled.

In above screenshot I can see "IFS" is the function which is not available in excel and that's why you are getting #NAME error.

Comment: Go back and reread my comment then reread your narrative and finally take a good look at the image you provided and make some sense of it all.

Comment: Here what i am checking is "From the column "Work Geography" Range("A2") value is equal to "Work Country" Range("B2") or not.

Comment: @AbhinavAsthana [Ehrm.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45)

Comment: @GyanaPrakash You are overdoing it, just check if A# = B# as `=$A2=$B2` and it will result in either **True** for equal values or **False** for unequal. And by the way, what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Hello AntiDrondert, I am using MS Office Professional Plus 2013.

Comment: @GyanaPrakash Even though `IFS` function DO exist, you can't use it in Excel-2013, it was implemented later, in Excel-2016. If you want to check for multiple conditions, you can use nested `IF`s

Comment: Hello AntiDrondert, previously i was using in that method only, But in the current raw data one column that have forget to select so it result the entire report itself came wrong when they run the macros, that is why just asked is there any other way to check the values in the both the columns are same or not.

Comment: @AntiDrondert has your answer as far as the query is concerned (you are over complicating the formula). If the column aren't always in the same location, you can use VBA to first find the columns and then set the formulas in your `Status` column via VBA. Have you got any experience of VBA?

Comment: Hello Friends, Here everyone is not genius and all are here to help each other, Why everyone is  downgrading my question, If you can't help me sit quite and watch the comments given by other. Once again my humble request do not downgrade my question.

Comment: I have some experience, but not expect on writing code like this scenario.

Comment: In my Experience this my first question getting downgraded to -4 felling very bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There could be multiple reasons for this error:

- **IFS function is not defined in MS Office Professional Plus 2013**, you are using a function that is not enabled in your version of Excel.
- **Your formula has a reference to a name that is not defined in Excel**, you are obviously using named range (`Work Geography` and `Work Country`) but you could forget to define them.
- **There is a typo**, it is either in `Work Geography` or `Work Country` or both, because name can't hold space characters.
- **Logic is flawed**, using `IF` function on values which are not boolean could lead to unepxpected results.

Formula I would use:

```
=IF(A2=B2, "Local", "Expat")
```

Thanks to @Zac for clarifications.
This is what I came up with:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CheckCountries()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Dim rngGeo As Range, rngCountry As Range, rngStatus As Range
    Dim rngData As Range

    '    Define Sheet1
    Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    '    I assumed headers are constantly on the first row
    '    Find cells with needed headers
    Set rngGeo = MySheet.Rows(1).Find("Work Geography", , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns)
    Set rngCountry = MySheet.Rows(1).Find("Work Country", , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns)
    Set rngStatus = MySheet.Rows(1).Find("Status", , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns)

    '    Your big table, excluding headers
    With MySheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rngData = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
    End With
    
    '    Define needed columns
    Set rngGeo = Intersect(rngData, rngGeo.EntireColumn)
    Set rngCountry = Intersect(rngData, rngCountry.EntireColumn)
    Set rngStatus = Intersect(rngData, rngStatus.EntireColumn)

    '    Calculate
    rngStatus.Value _
        = Evaluate("=IF(" & rngGeo.Address & "=" & rngCountry.Address & ", " & _
                        """Local"", " & _
                        """Expat"")")
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree that OP's query has a few issues (as you have outlined) but what you've provided as an answer is not the solution to OP's query.. it's an analysis of possible (most likely probable) issues with OP's query. Although I agree with what you have outlined, I'm not convinced that it should have been provided as an answer

Comment: @Zac Should I add formula at the end to improve my answer? I was a bit lost, when I read the question title and question itself as they both refer to different problems (Column comparison and #NAME? calculating). Which of them should I answer?

Comment: Hello AntiDrondert, I reversed my vote, But i should appreciated you for providing this useful information.

Comment: From what I understand, OP's question is 2 folds: 1. there are issues with OP's formula. 2. the columns aren't always in 'the same place'. I suspect that answer would probably be a combination of VBA and formula. I think the formula you have now will work but would need some VBA to find the columns in the first instance and then use VBA to implement your formula

Comment: Hello AntiDrondert, Thank you so much for helping me, This code works perfectly, I will never forget you in my life. Once again thank you.